# Relative pruning/word deletion results in error of Structural topic modeling

Tags: r, topic-modeling

I am trying to use a structural topic model to look at topic changes in YouTube comments and i am following this website.: https://bookdown.org/valerie_hase/TextasData_HS2021/tutorial-13-topic-modeling.html

```
tokens <- data_pr$content %>%
     tokens(what = "word",
     remove_punct = TRUE,
     remove_numbers = TRUE,
     remove_url = TRUE) 

#applying relative pruning

dfm <- dfm_trim(dfm(tokens), 
 min_docfreq = 0.02,
 max_docfreq = 0.99,
 docfreq_type = "prop", verbose = TRUE)

#removing further words
dfm = dfm_remove(dfm, c("d", "dass", "war", "haben", "sein", "mal", "gar" ))
dfm <- dfm_replace(dfm, "videos", "video" )


# Stm Model

model <- stm(documents = dfm_stm$documents,
         vocab = dfm_stm$vocab, 
         K = 6,
         prevalence = ~year,
         data = data_pr,
         verbose = TRUE)
```

The model works, unless I use relative pruning or I delete words which my preprocessing of the tokens didnt find. Because the original data containing the meta data and my dfm dont have the same amount of observations i get the following error:
(In this example I have only deleated some words like "dass" which my stopword list didn't find.)

```
"Error in stm(documents = dfm_stm$documents, vocab = dfm_stm$vocab, K = 10,  : 
 number of observations in content covariate (9913) prevalence covariate (9915) and documents    (9913) are not all equal."
```

I am wondering how to deal with this, since even in the tutorial I use the use relative pruning of tokens
.

Thank you for your help!

I tried the model without relative pruning and it works. I am now wondering if I need to preprocess all the data before creating the dfm, but thats not how the tutorials do it.

Comment: Based on the tutorial, it looks like you missed a step. (It happens to the best of us!)  After removing words, use `convert` (Step 13.3). Let me know if this doesn't pan out.

Comment: Oh I realized,  I didn't put this into my question. But I did the step, unfortunately, that's not the reason. Thank you for your answer!